# Error in converting datas from string to int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe `cleaned_bp['VISITCODE']` which looks like:

```
0          1
1          2
2          3
3          6
4          9
5         12
6         15
```

where the non-index column consists of strings.
I wanted to convert them to integers by doing:

```
for i in range(len(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'])):
    cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'][i] = int(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'][i])
```

but I get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-4d6508c1abda> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'])):
----> 2     cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'][i] = int(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'][i])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2475         try:
   2476             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2477                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2478         except KeyError as e1:
   2479             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 13
```

what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Any reason to not just use `cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'].astype(int)` or `pandas.to_numeric` ?

Comment: @JonClements did not know about them. Will use them. Still curious why the method in the question doesnt work though

Comment: Because `cleaned_np['VISITCODE'][i]` will try and access the *index* relating to the column - not the *position* as though it was a list. It implies your index column isn't identical to `range(len(your_df))`... If you changed it to `iloc[i]` it'd work... You might want to read up on indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in range(len(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'])):
    cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'].iloc[i] = int(cleaned_bp['VISITCODE'].iloc[i])
```

This will use the position in the index not the index itself.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pandas you can try:

```
cleaned_bp.VISITCODE.astype(int)
```